How to store bytes into SRAM (Cache memory)
Is there any instruction on assembly that allocates memory in the SRAM of any level? Is that possible?
I am waiting for some C intrinsic (may be SSSE4) of assembly instructions to allocate memory in cache, if it even possible.
